# Limit of infinite product

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Is it possible to find an analytic form for the limit of the infinite product:

$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1+x^{\delta^n}}{2}
$$

where $ x>0 $ and $0<\delta<1$?

Comment: You may start with $\,\delta=\dfrac 12\,$ : I obtained $\dfrac{x-1}{\log(x)}$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me hint of how you got there?

Comment: For $\,\delta=\dfrac 12\,$ (the other cases should not be so easy...) you only need to expand the product of the $m$ first numerators in increasing powers of $x$. You should get a geometric series and finally the fraction $$P_m(x):=\frac {1-x}{(1-x^{1/2^m})2^m}$$ At the limit $m\to +\infty$ you'll get $\dfrac{x-1}{\log(x)}$. I don't know how to handle the general case $\,\delta\neq\dfrac 12$. For $\,\delta =\dfrac 1d$ only the powers represented in base $d$ with $0$ and $1$ will be considered (I didn't search further...)